# static final field in public nested class

Tags: java, eclipse

I have such code:

```
public class Foo {
    public class Bar implements Parcelable {
        public static final Parcelable.Creator<Type> CREATOR =
                   new Parcelable.Creator<Type>() {
                   @Override
                   ....
        }
    }
}
```

Eclipse says:

```
The field CREATOR cannot be declared static in a non-static inner type, unless 
initialized with a constant expression
```

Please tell me what is it? I think it is because I have a nested class, but I don't know, how to correct the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The inner class cannot have static methods... If you want to have it, you need to define Bar as static as well.

Otherwise, the field must be declared as non-static.

Comment: I don't think defining Bar as static will allow one to have a static variable within it.  Not working for me anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Although I do not know why, static fields and methods in inner classes are prohibited by Java. The only way to work around this to declare a static inner class; or of course you can make your field in the nested class non-static.